# Keyboard shortcut for moving mouse to focused window for MacOs?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut for Mac OS, or a setting, to make the mouse cursor "jump" to the currently focused window?

I use a dual monitor setup, and after CmD + Tab -ing to a window on the adjacent screen, it would be rather helpful to jump the mouse cursor to the center of it (sort of a like a reverse focus follow).